# Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\UsoSueloController::store() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code:

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\UsoSuelo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Imports\UsoSueloImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use storeTrait;

class UsoSueloController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $file= 'uso_suelo.csv';
        $this->store($file);
    }
```

I use a trait because a have more controllers like this

**app/Traits**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Imports\UsoSueloImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

trait storeTrait{

    public function store($file) {
        Excel::import(new UsoSueloImport, $file); 
    }
}
```

this gives me the following error

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\UsoSueloController::store() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given, called in C:\Users\pachi\Documents\Version_web\mpe_web\app\Http\Controllers\UsoSueloController.php on line 30
```

Help pls

Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php assumes you are calling `store()` method of the controller, if you want to use the same name for the trait method as the controllers method you need to change the name of the traits method when you call it within the controller class (which you didn't do at all).

```php
class UsoSueloController extends Controller
{
    use storeTrait  {
      store as storeFile;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file= 'uso_suelo.csv';
        $this->storeFile($file);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i have another error:could not find the file, but I realized that in namespace it was wrong: I changed it to namespace App\Traits; and it worked well

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing

```
$this->store
```

You're calling the controller method and not using the trait.  This is because the methods have the same name.  You need [Conflict resolution.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict)

So...

```
    use storeTrait { store as traitStore };
class UsoSueloController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $file= 'uso_suelo.csv';
        $this->traitStore($file);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
trait storeTrait{

    public function store(Request $request, $file) {
        Excel::import(new UsoSueloImport, $file); 
    }
}
```